# Is there a way to remove a character from a string in this program?

Tags: c#

I am tasked with reading the first character in the sentence and count how many times that character occurs. I must then move on to the next character that has not been counted yet and

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            char[] array = fullword.ToCharArray();

            foreach (char ch in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(GetHowManyTimeOccurenceCharInString(fullword, ch));
            }
        }

        public static int GetHowManyTimeOccurenceCharInString(string text, char c)
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (char ch in text)
            {
                if (ch.Equals(c))
                {                  
                    count++;                    
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

    }
```

Comment: hi perhaps keep track of which characters have been seen with an array or map

Comment: Any examples of how to do that ?

Comment: There are Jack and Jill again :-). I would suggest changing the array to a List<char>. You can easily remove chars from a List.

Comment: Any way to go about on doing this, I am new to programming and still learning the ropes of it :)

Comment: You are counting every char you see and don't remove them. That's why you count them twice

Comment: Is there a way to not count the chars twice ?

Comment: Change that fullword: replace the char you just counted with an empty string (all occurrences). As a debug step: print the replaced string to check that it went OK. Careful:Replace has multiple overloads, you want to replace a string, not a char (empty char doesn't exist)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here it is. Just a little program to show you how to do that. First convert your string into a Char arrar and add that to a List. Then you can remove chars from the list using the RemoveAt(n) method. Finally you change your list into a string again and voila there are "JackandJill" again.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace RemoveChars
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = "Jack and Jill";

            var list = new List<char>();

            list.AddRange(name.ToCharArray());

            list.RemoveAt(4);
            list.RemoveAt(7);

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            list.ForEach(x => sb.Append(x));

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand how to remove it thank you but in my case once I how many times each character occurred in the sentence for example. We start at J in jack and move through the whole sentence which includes the word matches until the end of Jill. We carry on but when I reach the 'a' in matches I do not want to count it again because I have done so already with the 'a' in Jack

Comment: That is the problem I am having

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to get the number of character occurrences in a string.

This will give you a dictionary of **character** and **count**.

```
public Dictionary<char, int> GetNoOfOccurenceCharInString(string stringToCheck)
    {
        //Track the character and count in a Dictionary.
        Dictionary<char, int> map = new Dictionary<char, int>();
   
        //For String "Jack and Jill" it will store something like this in the memory
        // j =2, a = 2, c = 1, k = 1, " " = 2, n = 1, d = 1, i = 1, l = 2
   
       //Shift to Lower case and Loop through each character
        foreach (var c in stringToCheck.ToLower()) 
        {
           if (c == ' ') //If the current char is a space do not count;
           {
               continue;
           }

            //Check if map already has the char, if yes use the count stored in the memory, else initialize to 0
            var count = map.ContainsKey(c) ? map[c] : 0;

            map[c] = count + 1; //Increment count by 1
        }

        return map;
    }
```

To test this:

```
string name1 = "Jack";
string matches = "matches";
string name2 = "Jill";
string fullword = name1 + matches + name2;

//Call our method
var result = GetNoOfOccurenceCharInString(fullword);

//loop through each key in the Dictionary
foreach (var key in result.Keys)
{
   //Print out the Key and the Count
    Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {result[key]}");
}
```

Comment: You should give some explanation to what you are doing. This a newby programmer.

Comment: This is right yes but i do not want any duplicate iterations being added

Comment: This is giving me 15 outputs whereas i only need 11 outputs

Comment: @SudhirSanjiv I think it gave you 15 outputs because of lowercase and uppercase characters. Also if you have space in your input it would be included in the count

Comment: @PaulSinnema Added Comments,

Comment: I am getting this error in the output - System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Char,System.Int32]

Comment: @SudhirSanjiv. It is not an error, you are writing the dictionary to the Console. I added how you can test this. Try reading up on dictionaries and data structures in C#, very helpful :)

Comment: Last question :) Where is result.keys coming from ? Will read up on that thank you !

Comment: @SudhirSanjiv: Sorry, forgot to call the method, check the solution. Updated. Please accept the answer in stackoverflow if it works for you.

Comment: You deserve an award :) All is working well now!

Comment: @SudhirSanjiv You're welcome, all I ask of you is Pass it forward. 
when you become experienced, teach someone who needs help :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you need is to create a counting HashMap. I will put this example made in java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name1 = "jack";
    String matches = "matches";
    String name2 = "jill";

    String fullWord = name1 + matches + name2;
    //Map to get the number of repeated characters
    HashMap<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>(); 
    
    //New string without repeated characters
    StringBuilder noRepeatingCharacter = new StringBuilder();
    // Text string with the number of repeated characters
    StringBuilder literalCounts = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < fullWord.length(); i++) {
        //We get the character to establish if it is repeated or not.
        char charAr = fullWord.charAt(i);
        //We verify if in our map the character exists
        if (counts.containsKey(charAr)) {
            // Update counts
            counts.replace(charAr, counts.get(charAr) + 1);
        } else {
            // we add to our new string of characters only the non-repeated ones
            noRepeatingCharacter.append(charAr);
            // If the character does not exist in our map, we add it
            counts.put(charAr, 1);
        }
    }
    
    // So that we can print the count in order, we assign to our variable literalCounts
    for (int i = 0; i < noRepeatingCharacter.length(); i++) {
        char charAr = noRepeatingCharacter.charAt(i);
        literalCounts.append(counts.get(charAr));
    }
    // Print counts
    System.out.println("Counts: " + literalCounts);
}
```

Output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP84U.png)